# Object array rendered as empty array in Swagger UI

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I have the following model definitions in an OpenAPI/Swagger spec:

```
"definitions": {
    "models.Equipment": {
        "title": "Equipment",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "Features": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/models.Feature"
                }
            },
            "Id": {
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int64"
            },
            "IdType": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Name": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Price": {
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int32"
            }
        }
    },
    "models.Feature": {
        "title": "Feature",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "Equipments": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/models.Equipment"
                }
            },
            "Id": {
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int64"
            },
            "IdFeature": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/models.Feature"
            },
            "Name": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the `Feature` model, he `Equipments` property is defined as an array of `Equipment` models, but Swagger UI 3.x renders it as an empty array `[]`. Everywhere `Feature` model is used, like as examples for `POST` method in `Feature` I have this kind of display.

[image: swagger-ui bug]

Is the definition incorrect in some way?

The complete spec is here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/anjfhgxhr0pfmnu/swagger-bug.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Swagger UI and is most likely caused by circular references in your models - `models.Equipment` references `models.Feature`, and `models.Feature` references `models.Equipment`. You can open an issue in the [Swagger UI repository](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) on GitHub.

Your spec also contains errors in the response definitions:

```
        "responses": {
            "200": {
                "schema": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/models.Equipment"
                }
            },
            "403": {}
        }
```

Each response [must have a `description`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#responseObject), so the correct version would be:

```
        "responses": {
            "200": {
                "description": "OK",
                "schema": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/models.Equipment"
                }
            },
            "403": {
                "description": "Oops"
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for rephrasing everything, I have been very lazy about this question, sorry for that. Thank you again for spotting the error! :) Here is the issue I reported: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3325